# HTML embedded tables

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am encountering a strange problem.. This is a rough version of my code:

```
<table>
<table>
<tr><td>
while(mysql_fetch())
{
<table>
<tr><td>Hi</td></tr>
</table>
}
</td></tr>
</table>
</table>
```

My problem is that the table being created inside the while loop is being created on a new line (row) when it's supposed to be printed in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            while(mysql_fetch()) {
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Hi</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Should work. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut6Pr/)

Comment: awesome thanks you, that looks like the solution, i will try it :)

Comment: @Dan If this solved your problem please "accept" this answer.